# are Ultra sound signal amplitude dangerous?

Tags: amplitude, wave, ultrasound

First sorry if this question if it's out of topic but I'm very intrigued

The human ear can hear a specific range of sound waves frequency. and huge amplitude of those sounds can damage the ears

but the ultrasound waves that the ear could not hear, if their amplitude exceeds 100dB for example, my question is :

- couldn't that be a huge danger too to the ear?
- if so, since we can't hear the sound, how can we react to that danger !!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if it's the proper forum, but there some research done on the subject

http://www.hse.gov.uk/research/crr_pdf/2001/crr01343.pdf

Basically, there are limits even in ultrasound, but they are higher than 20Hz-20khz sounds

Comment: there are also issues regarding ultrasound and the human fetus.  some question if the benefit gained from the image is worth blasting a pre-born baby with high-intensity acoustic energy.  kids have better hearing than we old farts.  just because a blast of ultrasound isn't noticed by me doesn't mean it ain't noticed by a 32-week-old fetus.

Comment: Medical ultrasound is north of 1 MHz. That ought to be safely out of the "unknown" hearing range of a fetus.